# XSL Transform of Nested Attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, filemaker

My task at hand is to strip the Text and any associated Font Attributes from the following (simplified) example XML into a FileMaker database.  Example XML:

```
<Font Id="Arial" Script="normal" Size="32" Underlined="no" Italic="no" Weight="normal">
    <Paragraph>
        <Text>This <Font Italic="yes">word</Font> is italic</Text>
        <Text>This entire line has no formatting</Text>
        <Text>This<Font Italic="yes">line</Font><Font Underlined="yes" Italic = "yes"> has multiple formats</Font></Text>
    </Paragraph>

    <Paragraph>
        <Text>This is the first line of the second paragraph and has no formatting</Text>
        <Text>This line also has no formatting</Text>
        <Text><Font Underlined="yes">This entire line is underlined</Font></Text>
    </Paragraph>
</Font>
```

As you can see, the `<Paragraph>` element is enclosed by a ` node. (I hope I am referring to these parts correctly). I have been successful in writing code to transfer the individual FULL lines of text into the database along with the nested Font attribute(s) when there is either NO nested Font attribute(s), or if the nested Font attribute(s) enclose the ENTIRE Text data. 
What I'm stuck on is how to deal with lines of text that have nested attributes WITHIN the text data, such as the first line in the first paragraph and the third line in the first paragraph.

What I'm looking to do is capture each snippet of data, along with its attributes. My schema allows for up to three nested Font attributes per line of text (a, b, c). Using the example XML file, my FileMaker database should look like this (simplified) for Paragraph 1:

> ```
> Record 1
> Line 1a Text: This
> Line 1a Italic: (no value)
> Line 1a Underlined: (no value)
>
> Line 1b Text: word
> Line 1b Italic: yes
> Line 1b Underlined: (no value)
>
> Line 1c Text: is italic
> Line 1c Italic: (no value)
> Line 1c Underlined: (no value)
>
> Line 2a Text: This entire line has no formatting
> Line 2a Italic: (no value)
> Line 2a Underlined: (no value)
>
> Line 2b Text: (no value)
> Line 2b Italic:  (no value)
> Line 2b Underlined: (no value)
>
> Line 2c Text: (no value)
> Line 2c Italic: (no value)
> Line 2c Underlined: (no value)
>
> Line 3a Text: This
> Line 3a Italic: (no value)
> Line 3a Underlined: (no value)
>
> Line 3b Text: line
> Line 3b Italic: yes
> Line 3b Underlined: (no value)
>
> Line 3c Text: has multiple formats
> Line 3c Italic: yes
> Line 3c Underlined: yes
> ```

Of course, I will not be able to predict when and where formatting will be applied.  I hope I have been clear, and thank you very much, in advance, for any pointers that you can provide to help me accomplish this task.

Comment: You might want to add the actual output format you expect from that. XSLT is an XML *transformation* language. In other words, it can transform XML into a different format. It cannot feed your database, or anything like that. Specify a file format that your database can actually read, the sample above may outline your intent - but it's not anything you will be able to actually work with.

Comment: The format you present as the result is very problematic, and can only work if each `Paragraph` (record) has exactly the same number of text segments (fields) - which doesn't seem very likely. If you want to "*capture each snippet of data, along with its attributes*" then you should create a separate record for each segment.

Comment: @Tomalak The question is tagged `filemaker`. That specifies the target XML schema.

Comment: @michael I take it that the filemaker XML schema is not common knowledge (and that it's not our job to look it up, either).

Comment: Thanks for your response. XSLT actually works quite well as a bridge between Filemaker and an XML document. Perhaps I did not provide enough information. Below is the current XSLT code that works for an entire line of text without nested Font attributes, or for a line of text that is entirely enclosed by the Font attribute(s):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you try something like this, at least as your starting point:

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Font">
    <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
        <METADATA>
            <FIELD NAME="Text"/>
            <FIELD NAME="IsItalic" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
            <FIELD NAME="IsUnderline" TYPE="TEXT"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Paragraph" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        </METADATA>
        <RESULTSET>
            <!-- create a record for each text node, descendant of Paragraph -->
            <xsl:for-each select="Paragraph//text()">
                <ROW>
                    <!-- get the value of the current text node itself  -->
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="."/></DATA></COL>
                    <!-- get the value of @Italic from the nearest ancestor that has such attribute -->
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::*[@Italic][1]/@Italic"/></DATA></COL>
                    <!-- get the value of @Underlined from the nearest ancestor that has such attribute -->
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::*[@Underlined][1]/@Underlined"/></DATA></COL>
                    <!-- get the ID of the ancestor Paragraph -->
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="generate-id(ancestor::Paragraph)"/></DATA></COL>
                </ROW>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </RESULTSET>
    </FMPXMLRESULT>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, you will get:

[image]

Note that the paragraph ID's are unique within the scope of the current transformation only, not universally.

---

### Added:

Against my better judgment, here's a stylesheet that will create a record for each `Paragraph`, with each record being a strict grid of 3 lines by 3 text nodes.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Font">
    <FMPXMLRESULT>
        <METADATA>
            <FIELD NAME="Line 1a Text"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Line 1a Italic"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Line 1a Underlined"/>

            <FIELD NAME="Line 1b Text"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Line 1b Italic"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Line 1b Underlined"/>

            <FIELD NAME="Line 1c Text"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Line 1c Italic"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Line 1c Underlined"/>

            <FIELD NAME="Line 2a Text"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Line 2a Italic"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Line 2a Underlined"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Line 2b Text"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Line 2b Italic"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Line 2b Underlined"/>

            <FIELD NAME="Line 2c Text"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Line 2c Italic"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Line 2c Underlined"/>

            <FIELD NAME="Line 3a Text"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Line 3a Italic"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Line 3a Underlined"/>

            <FIELD NAME="Line 3b Text"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Line 3b Italic"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Line 3b Underlined"/>

            <FIELD NAME="Line 3c Text"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Line 3c Italic"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Line 3c Underlined"/>
        </METADATA>
        <RESULTSET>
            <!-- create a record for each Paragraph -->
            <xsl:for-each select="Paragraph">
                <ROW>
                    <!-- for each line ...  -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="Text">
                        <xsl:variable name="text-nodes" select=".//text()" />
                        <!-- process the first three text nodes  -->
                        <xsl:call-template name="create-cells">
                            <xsl:with-param name="text-node" select="$text-nodes[1]"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                        <xsl:call-template name="create-cells">
                            <xsl:with-param name="text-node" select="$text-nodes[2]"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                        <xsl:call-template name="create-cells">
                            <xsl:with-param name="text-node" select="$text-nodes[3]"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:for-each> 
                </ROW>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </RESULTSET>
    </FMPXMLRESULT>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="create-cells">
    <xsl:param name="text-node"/>
    <!-- get the value of the text node itself  -->
    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="$text-node"/></DATA></COL>
    <!-- get the value of @Italic from the nearest ancestor that has such attribute -->
    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="$text-node/ancestor::*[@Italic][1]/@Italic"/></DATA></COL>
    <!-- get the value of @Underlined from the nearest ancestor that has such attribute -->
    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="$text-node/ancestor::*[@Underlined][1]/@Underlined"/></DATA></COL>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result will look something like this (two records shown in List view):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!  This looks like it's going to be perfect. The problem is, I don't quite understand what's going on. As I am not an expert at XSLT (yet!), I wonder if you could point me to a resource that explains things like the use of the double forward slash in Paragraph//text, the period in select="." and the what  *[Underlined][1] is instructing the code to look for.

Comment: @JonathanA I have added some comments to code. As for resources, there are tutorials, books and finally the [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath) and [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) standards themselves.

Comment: Yup...been scouring the web and forums for hours long before posting here. Didn't find anything yet that really explained it adequately. Once again, thank you for taking the time to assist...you've definitely sent me on the right path!

Comment: Curious how the above code can be modified to strip each paragraph into a single FileMaker record (obviously with multiple fields), as opposed to separate records for each text snippet.

Comment: @JonathanA As I said in my comment to your question, you would have problems with this, because the number of required fields is unknown in advance. You cannot create fields while you import, like you can records. In addition, it would be be very poor database structure to have. Just think: in order to find all italicized texts, you would have to search *n* fields instead of just one - and you wouldn't be able to present them in isolation.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, I absolutely agree. But in the scenario that I'm working with (a tightly-controlled specification of  three lines per paragraph (max), and three unique font attributes per line (max)), in my opinion this is very manageable. I am very intrigued by the technique of serializing of the paragraphs, but in my scenario--using an existing database structure--that will require pre-importing the data to a scratch table and then looping/searching through all the records by the serial number to get the data into into a single record. So if I can do it up from, all the better!

Comment: "*in my opinion this is very manageable*" I strongly suspect that the opposite is true - but even if I discard that, you're still not addressing the primary issue here: are you willing to set a limit to the number of "lines" a paragraph can have, and to the number of text nodes in each line?

Comment: Yes I am...it's a purpose-built database for a very specific situation. Absolutely agree that what I would like to do here is not extensible, which your method obviously is.   So how about I approach the question from the standpoint of expanding my knowledge of what is possible (whether or not it is advisable): What does it take to strip all the data into a single record that has multiple fields, such as Text1a, Text1b, Text 1c, Text2a, Text2b, etc?    And let it not go unsaid: I thoroughly appreciate your responses thus far...quite educational.

Comment: @JonathanA See the addition to my answer.

Comment: A thing of beauty. You rock. Thank you very much, again. I hope to be able to return the favor.

Comment: Ran into 1 snag...is it possible to have the create-cells block only parse the Font attributes that may be contained within each Text element, and not reach back into the top level Font element?

Comment: You could use `<xsl:value-of select="$text-node/../@Italic"/>`. But then the result will be either `yes` or empty, I think.

Comment: That'll actually be perfect. I was doing a lot of reading today (thanks for the links) and was heading in that direction, but couldn't get it to work. I think it was because I was using only a single period between the forward slashes.